# Get the Short value set by the user in the text view

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, mobile-application

I want to get the value which is entered by the user in the `EditText`, but the value must be in a Short (not String). For an example, in this following case, if `valeur` was a short, how should I do it?

```
valeur = ETadresseip1.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
String value = ETadresseip1.getText().toString();
try {
   valeur = Short.parseShort(value);
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
   // Error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
try{
    String srting = ETadresseip1.getText().toString().trim();
    valeur = Short.parseShort(srting );
}catch(NumberFormatException ne){
}
```